# How to fill step by step DataFrame according to the indeces?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df = df.append({'A': ['AB', 'C', 'CD', 'DC']}, ignore_index = True)
df.to_csv('df.csv', index = False)


# Another place in the code
a = 5
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')
df = df.append({'B': a}, ignore_index = True)
df.to_csv('df.csv', index = False)
```

The code gives:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

How to correct the code, please? I would like to set indexes when ['AB', 'C', 'CD', 'DC'] list is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({'A': ['AB', 'C', 'CD', 'DC']})])
```

Your solution:

```
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'A': ['AB', 'C', 'CD', 'DC']}))
```

In another columns are created missing values, so is possible replace them by:

```
a = 5
df = df.fillna(pd.DataFrame({'B': a}, index=[0]))
```

Another idea:

```
df.loc[0, 'B'] = a
```

Comment: Thank you and how to fill other cells according to indices?

Comment: @Anna-Kat - Can you test now?